# Is there any way of writing a section of HTML so that a CSS selector would produce an infinite loop?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to write `HTML` to that a `CSS` selector will search for an element until the call stack is maxed out? There has to be some way of doing it with nested `div`s or something like that.

Comment: No, because CSS does not have a parent selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No because there is no parent selector. Selectors can only match children or neighbors. So eventually they will select to the end of the tree.